# how to get combined legend in ggplot2 when I have both geom_line and geom_hline

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have data as follows in a file `wiki-hier.dat`:

```
    1     2     5     10    20
2   80.77 80.76 80.77 80.77 80.77
3   83.06 83.11 83.11 83.11 83.11
4   84.40 84.46 84.43 84.44 84.43
5   85.24 85.31 85.31 85.31 85.31
6   85.92 86.03 86.02 86.02 86.01
7   86.41 86.56 86.55 86.55 86.55
8   86.62 86.76 86.77 86.77 86.77
10  87.13 87.32 87.32 87.32 87.32
12  87.50 87.71 87.68 87.69 NA
14  87.72 87.93 87.94 87.94 87.94
16  87.82 88.08 88.10 88.10 NA
18  87.87 88.15 88.17 88.17 88.17
20  87.93 88.22 88.23 88.23 88.23
24  88.10 88.39 88.40 88.41 88.40
28  88.10 88.46 88.47 88.47 88.47
32  88.12 88.46 88.49 88.49 NA
36  88.16 88.50 88.52 88.52 88.52
40  88.12 88.49 88.50 88.50 88.50
50  88.11 88.48 88.45 88.44 NA
60  87.90 88.26 88.25 88.25 NA
70  87.73 88.05 88.05 88.04 NA
80  87.60 87.89 87.90 87.89 NA
100 87.38 87.66 87.63 87.62 NA
120 87.01 87.23 87.23 87.23 NA
150 86.73 86.91 86.90 86.89 NA
200 86.04 86.14 86.08 86.06 NA
250 85.62 85.59 85.53 85.51 NA
```

I'm trying to plot this using ggplot2. My code is as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
t = read.table("wiki-hier.dat", header=TRUE)
t$x = as.numeric(rownames(t))
data = data.frame(x = rep(t$x, 2), acc = c(t$X1, t$X2),
   beam = factor(rep(c(1,2), each=length(t$x))))
pdf("plotlines-wiki-hier-ggplot.pdf")
p = qplot(x, acc, data = data, geom = c("line", "point"),
    group = beam, color = beam, shape = beam, linetype = beam) +
  xlab("K-d subdivision factor") +
  ylab("Acc@161 (pct)") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=84.49, linetype="Naive Bayes"), show_guide=TRUE) +
  scale_linetype_manual("beam", values = c(1,3,2))
print(p)
dev.off()
```

The problem is, I get two legends, and I only want one:

[image]

This one legend should have colors, shapes and linetypes in it for the keys "1" and "2".

How do I fix this?

The next-best thing would be to have two legends, one containing only the keys "1" and "2" and the other containing only the key "Naive Bayes".

Comment: pressed for time at the moment, but this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148679/ggplot2-need-to-construct-a-manual-legend-for-complicated-plot might help get you started constructing a custom legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create another dataframe which you can map the aesthetics to similar to your main data.

```
#Your data

dat <- structure(list(X1 = c(80.77, 83.06, 84.4, 85.24, 85.92, 86.41, 
86.62, 87.13, 87.5, 87.72, 87.82, 87.87, 87.93, 88.1, 88.1, 88.12, 
88.16, 88.12, 88.11, 87.9, 87.73, 87.6, 87.38, 87.01, 86.73, 
86.04, 85.62), X2 = c(80.76, 83.11, 84.46, 85.31, 86.03, 86.56, 
86.76, 87.32, 87.71, 87.93, 88.08, 88.15, 88.22, 88.39, 88.46, 
88.46, 88.5, 88.49, 88.48, 88.26, 88.05, 87.89, 87.66, 87.23, 
86.91, 86.14, 85.59), X5 = c(80.77, 83.11, 84.43, 85.31, 86.02, 
86.55, 86.77, 87.32, 87.68, 87.94, 88.1, 88.17, 88.23, 88.4, 
88.47, 88.49, 88.52, 88.5, 88.45, 88.25, 88.05, 87.9, 87.63, 
87.23, 86.9, 86.08, 85.53), X10 = c(80.77, 83.11, 84.44, 85.31, 
86.02, 86.55, 86.77, 87.32, 87.69, 87.94, 88.1, 88.17, 88.23, 
88.41, 88.47, 88.49, 88.52, 88.5, 88.44, 88.25, 88.04, 87.89, 
87.62, 87.23, 86.89, 86.06, 85.51), X20 = c(80.77, 83.11, 84.43, 
85.31, 86.01, 86.55, 86.77, 87.32, NA, 87.94, NA, 88.17, 88.23, 
88.4, 88.47, NA, 88.52, 88.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA)), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X5", "X10", "X20"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("2",     "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "10", "12", "14", "16", 
"18", "20", "24", "28", "32", "36", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "100", 
"120", "150", "200", "250"))


dat$x = as.numeric(rownames(dat))
dat = data.frame(x = rep(dat$x, 2), acc = c(dat$X1, dat$X2),
                  beam = factor(rep(c(1,2), each=length(dat$x))))

# Create a new dataframe for your horizontal line
newdf <-  data.frame(x=c(0,max(dat$x)), acc=84.49, beam='naive')

# or of you want the full horizontal lines
# newdf <-  data.frame(x=c(-Inf, Inf), acc=84.49, beam='naive')
```

Plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, acc, colour=beam, shape=beam, linetype=beam)) +
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data=newdf, aes(x,acc)) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values =c(1,3,2)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values =c(16,17, NA)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values =c("red", "blue", "black"))
```

I used `NA` to suppress the shape in the naive legend

[image]

**EDIT**

After re-reading perhaps all you need is this

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, acc, colour=beam, shape=beam, linetype=beam)) +
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=84.49), linetype="dashed")
```

Comment: Your edit suggestion doesn't work. That's the first thing I tried, and you don't see any legend for the geom_hline(). If you explicitly add the guide, you get two legends.

Comment: @UrbanVagabond; Apologies, i misunderstood: When reading "This one legend should have colors, shapes and linetypes in it for the keys "1" and "2"." I thought that that perhaps you may just want the one legend (although prob unlikely).

Comment: in any case, thanks for the solution! It works great.