# Why can't I change the shape of point using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to specific the shape of three kinds of points in my plot using ggplot2. However, no matter how I change the shape numbers, it doesn't work, the shapes of points been constantly set automatically.

Here is my code (the shape numbers are in the first line):

```
shape <- c("min"="1","max"="2",mean="3")

fill <- c("Rate"="#25c25b")

ggplot (data, aes(x=order))+

   geom_rect(aes(xmin=order-0.1, xmax=order+0.1, ymin = min, ymax=max), alpha=0, color="black")+

   geom_bar(aes(y=rate, fill="Rate"),stat="identity", alpha=0.3, width=0.5)+

   geom_point(aes(y=min, shape="min"), size=5)+ 

   geom_point(aes(y=mean, shape="mean"), size=5)+

   geom_point(aes(y=max, shape="max"), size=5)+

   labs(shape = "F0", fill = "Rate")
```

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the shape of points you need to use `scale_shape_manual()` and provide argument `values=` with shapes you need.

```
+ scale_shape_manual(values=c("min"=1,"max"=2,"mean"=3))
```

Comment: Oh! It works! Thank you!  But why I can change color using a data collection? e.g. : The first answer of the question below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148679/ggplot2-need-to-construct-a-manual-legend-for-complicated-plot

Comment: Also in the answer you linked they use `scale_color_manual()` and then provide colors.