# Create a legend for different models and datasets on same ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting two regressions models with the same independent variables and different independent variables in the same graph using `ggplot2`. I would like to add a legend that corresponds to each different dependent variable. Other posts have suggested using the `melt()` function to do this, however, it is unclear how to do these while preserving the model output. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100), y1 = rnorm(100), y2 = rnorm(100))
dat1 <- dat[,c(1,2,3)]
dat2 <- dat[,c(1,2,4)]

mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ x + z, data = dat1)
mod2 <- lm(y2 ~ x + z, data = dat2)


dat1$mod1 <- predict(mod1, newdata =dat1)  
err <- predict(mod1, newdata =dat1, se = TRUE)   
dat1$ucl <- err$fit + 1.96 * err$se.fit
dat1$lcl <- err$fit - 1.96 * err$se.fit   


dat2$mod2 <- predict(mod2, newdata =dat2)  
err <- predict(mod2, newdata =dat2, se = TRUE)   
dat2$ucl <- err$fit + 1.96 * err$se.fit
dat2$lcl <- err$fit - 1.96 * err$se.fit   


ggplot(dat1) + 
        geom_point(aes(x = x, y = mod1), size = .8, colour = "black") +
        geom_smooth(data = dat1, aes(x= x, y = mod1, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), 
                    size = 1, colour = "darkblue", se = TRUE, stat = "smooth", 
                    method = "lm") + 

        geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x = x, y = mod2), size = .8, colour = "black") +
        geom_smooth(data = dat2, aes(x= x, y = mod2, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl), 
                    size = 1, colour = "darkred", se = TRUE, stat = "smooth", 
                    method = "lm") + 
        scale_colour_manual(values = c("y1" = "darkred", "y2" = "red" ))
```

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Your call to `ggplot` uses 3 data frames (dat, dat1, dat2) but your code creates only `dat`. The answer will likely involve `melt()`, as you noted, but it will be easier to help you once you fix the data creation code to correspond to the data frames referenced by `ggplot`.

Comment: Apologies; appropriately edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. First we `gather` everything (this is the `tidyr` melt) and then plot it out. The key here is using `group = model` to separate out the data.
Given the data has been edited, we first need to recombine it like it was:

```
dat <- dat1
dat$mod2 <- dat2$mod2
```

Then we use tidyr to turn it into long data:

```
library(tidyr)
dat1 <- dat %>% gather(model, val, mod1, mod2)
```

Then we can plot (note the rearranging of aes, you can call it once and then inherit):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat1, aes(x = x, y = val, group = model)) + 
  geom_point( size = .8, colour = "black") +
  geom_smooth(aes(col=model), size = 1, se = TRUE, stat = "smooth", method = "lm")
```

As a side note, I'm not sure what you think you are doing with `ymax` and `ymin` inside `geom_smooth` - They have no effect here, the errors are calculated by `geom_smooth`. Maybe you want `geom_ribbon` to use your own errors?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great. Out of curiosity, is there any way to just add it manually without melting all of the models together first?

Comment: not [nearly as easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148679/ggplot2-need-to-construct-a-manual-legend-for-complicated-plot)