# How to Add legends manually to a integrade ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I combined two dataset in one plot, the observed distribution is built from "raw data" like "12,13,15,15,14,14,13,..."; while the expected distribution is built from probability like: "13 0.35;14 0.41; 15 0.23,..."

I combined them in one plot:
[image]

with the code below:

```
 ggplot(Obs_hetero,aes(x=K_i))+
  ggtitle("...") +
  xlab("No. of Heterozygous Loci (K)") + ylab("Frequency/Density")+
  geom_density(aes(x=K_i,y=..density..),colour="black",fill="red",alpha=.2)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=K,y=Density),color="blue",data = Expdist_K_unlinked) +
  geom_line(mapping=aes(x=x,y=y),colour="blue",data=spl,stat = "identity",size=1)+
  geom_area(mapping = aes(x=x,y=y),fill="blue",data=spl,alpha=.2)
```

After this, I would like to add a legend to this plot... But I cannot find how.

Comment: This question seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865121/how-to-name-data-in-legend-in-a-ggplot

Comment: For a start, you need to get `color` or `fill` inside `aes`

Comment: I tried that, but the color was not what I quote when I put them inside `aes`

Comment: Hi Sunny, do you mind sharing the dataset, for example do dput(Obs_hetero) and paste the output? I cannot quite get how all the variables fit inside a data.frame.

Comment: The original dataset is a little big. I can generate a small sample to share.