# How can I add a customized legend for multiple layers in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to make a line plot in ggplot2 using a data frame called df that looks something like this:

```
   DATE       ITEM        NUMBER_SOLD
    <date>     <chr>       <int>
 1 2018-01-08 APPLE         3
 2 2018-01-09 APPLE         3
 3 2018-01-09 PEAR          2
 4 2018-01-09 ORANGE        1
 5 2018-01-10 APPLE         2
 6 2018-01-10 PEAR          1
 7 2018-01-12 CHERRY        2
 8 2018-01-12 MANGO         1
 9 2018-01-15 PINEAPPLE     1
10 2018-01-15 APRICOT       1
```

etc

The data frame is basically a tibble showing how  many times a particular item was sold on a given day in 2018 with a total of 336 rows.

The plot needs to be a line plot showing the sale of one particular item (apple) with the date on the x axis, number sold on the y axis and an additional line on the y axis showing a 15% increase in sales like this:

```
df %>% filter(ITEM == "APPLE") %>%
  ggplot(aes(DATE, NUMBER_SOLD)) +
  geom_line(size = 1, col = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = NUMBER_SOLD + NUMBER_SOLD/100*15), col = "green4", size = 1, alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b", date_breaks  = "1 month")
```

However, I would also need to add a legend to show what both lines represent, e.g. red colored line representing the original number of sales and the green one representing the original number of sales + 15%. How might I achieve that?

Comment: I personally always recommend pictures to show the current and expected plot(s).

Comment: See questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148679/construct-a-manual-legend-for-a-complicated-plot), which use the `aes(colour = "Label 1")` trick. The alternative is to gather the data into a long format and plot them as a single layer, which will allow ggplot's automatic legending to work.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to do the calculation in the data frame first, then use `gather()` to turn the data to long and have the numbers into one column with another variable indicating whether each number is for actual or expected sale.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~"DATE",       ~"ITEM",        ~"NUMBER_SOLD",
"2018-01-08", "APPLE",         3,
"2018-01-09", "APPLE",         3,
"2018-01-09", "PEAR",          2,
"2018-01-09", "ORANGE",        1,
"2018-01-10", "APPLE",         2,
"2018-01-10", "PEAR",          1,
"2018-01-12", "CHERRY",        2,
"2018-01-12", "MANGO",         1,
"2018-01-15", "PINEAPPLE",     1,
"2018-01-15", "APRICOT",       1) %>% 
  mutate(DATE = parse_date(DATE),
         NUMBER_SOLD_EXP = NUMBER_SOLD + NUMBER_SOLD/100*15) %>% 
  gather(key = category, value = SOLD, NUMBER_SOLD, NUMBER_SOLD_EXP)

df
# A tibble: 20 x 4
   DATE       ITEM      category         SOLD
   <date>     <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
 1 2018-01-08 APPLE     NUMBER_SOLD      3   
 2 2018-01-09 APPLE     NUMBER_SOLD      3   
 3 2018-01-09 PEAR      NUMBER_SOLD      2   
 4 2018-01-09 ORANGE    NUMBER_SOLD      1   
 5 2018-01-10 APPLE     NUMBER_SOLD      2   
 6 2018-01-10 PEAR      NUMBER_SOLD      1   
 7 2018-01-12 CHERRY    NUMBER_SOLD      2   
 8 2018-01-12 MANGO     NUMBER_SOLD      1   
 9 2018-01-15 PINEAPPLE NUMBER_SOLD      1   
10 2018-01-15 APRICOT   NUMBER_SOLD      1   
11 2018-01-08 APPLE     NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  3.45
12 2018-01-09 APPLE     NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  3.45
13 2018-01-09 PEAR      NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  2.3 
14 2018-01-09 ORANGE    NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  1.15
15 2018-01-10 APPLE     NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  2.3 
16 2018-01-10 PEAR      NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  1.15
17 2018-01-12 CHERRY    NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  2.3 
18 2018-01-12 MANGO     NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  1.15
19 2018-01-15 PINEAPPLE NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  1.15
20 2018-01-15 APRICOT   NUMBER_SOLD_EXP  1.15
```

Now you just need to call `geom_line` once, using the colour argument on the variable indicating whether the number is actual or expected sold. You'll need to add `scale_colour_manual()` to specify what colour you want to attach to the categories.

```
df %>% filter(ITEM == "APPLE") %>%
  ggplot(aes(DATE, SOLD)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = category), size = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("NUMBER_SOLD" = "red", "NUMBER_SOLD_EXP" = "green")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b", date_breaks  = "1 month")
```

[image]